# Same elements different colors in css

Tags: css

what is the correct way to apply a different background color to the same element?
example

```
 <div id="mainmenumess">
   <p class="incmessage">must be blue</p>
   <p class="incmessage">must be red</p>
 </div>
```

css

```
#mainmenumess .incmessage{
-webkit-border-radius: 5;
-moz-border-radius: 5;
border-radius: 5px;
color: #ffffff;
background: #de2424;
padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
text-decoration: none;
cursor:pointer;
}

#mainmenumess .incmessage:hover {
background: #ed4747;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

And if is red must have hover blue dont had hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no "correct" there are many ways. Depending on which browsers you have to support and are there always just exactly two `<p>` elements inside `<div>` or could there be more...

this is one -> http://jsfiddle.net/0p3mxqgx/

```
 <div id="mainmenumess">
     <p class="incmessage">must be blue</p>
     <p class="incmessage">must be red</p>
</div>

#mainmenumess .incmessage {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5;
    -moz-border-radius: 5;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #de2424;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#mainmenumess .incmessage:first-child {
    background:blue;
}
#mainmenumess .incmessage:hover {
    background:blue;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#mainmenumess .incmessage:first-child:hover {
    background:red;
}
```

this is another: use `odd` and `even`  --> http://jsfiddle.net/0p3mxqgx/1/

```
#mainmenumess .incmessage {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5;
    -moz-border-radius: 5;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #de2424;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#mainmenumess .incmessage:nth-child(odd) {
    background:blue;
}
#mainmenumess .incmessage:nth-child(even):hover {
    background:blue;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#mainmenumess .incmessage:nth-child(odd):hover {
    background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd use `nth-child`.

```
.incmessage:nth-child(1) { background-color: blue; }
.incmessage:nth-child(1):hover { background-color: red; }

.incmessage:nth-child(2) { background-color: red; }
.incmessage:nth-child(2):hover { background-color: blue; }
```

Though, I'd consider adding classes to the elements cause this looks gross.

This wouldn't work in <= IE8.

Answer (score 2):

So from the sounds of it, the first one is red and all the others are blue? You'd want to do something like this:

```
#mainmenumess .incmessage:first-child {
    color: red;
}

#mainmenumess .incmessage {
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can select with nth child or pattern

here i have used 2n pattern for odd ones and 2n+1 for evens

```css
#mainmenumess .incmessage{
-webkit-border-radius: 5;
-moz-border-radius: 5;
border-radius: 5px;
color: #ffffff;

padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
text-decoration: none;
cursor:pointer;
}

#mainmenumess .incmessage:hover {
background: #ed4747;
text-decoration: none;
}
#mainmenumess .incmessage:nth-child(2n) { background-color: blue; }
#mainmenumess .incmessage:nth-child(2n+1) { background-color: red; }

#mainmenumess .incmessage:nth-child(2n):hover { background-color: red; }
#mainmenumess .incmessage:nth-child(2n+1):hover { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<div id="mainmenumess">
  <p class="incmessage">must be blue</p>
  <p class="incmessage">must be red</p>
  <p class="incmessage">must be red</p>
  <p class="incmessage">must be red</p>
</div>
```